# Publishing with lerna after prerelease without using force-publish

Tags: package, lerna, npm-publish, npm-package

we currently have the following workflow.

1. ticket comes in (eg. BRAND-1234)
2. we create a branch and work on the ticket and commit and push
3. for testing, we do then `yarn lerna publish preminor --preid BRAND-1234`
4. now other collegues can use `v1.2.3-BRAND-1234` during development
5. we do a pull request and if all is good, we would like to publish a minor version
6. so we do `yarn lerna publish minor --force-publish`

we need to do currently force publish because after a merge, nothing really changed, and the pushed head was already publish with the preid tag.

For me this feels like an hack, because we need to use "force". Also this means, that other packages, that did not change, will get a version bump.

So my question: **What is the correct workflow to work with prerelease tags and then publish a minor/major/patch version without using force and without having to change something just for the sake of change detection**

Comment: Wondering have you found an answer? Facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

try use

```
yarn lerna publish minor ----include-merged-tags
```